# Как обыграть z-index

Tags: css3, html5

Нужно что бы при заходе на .wrapper линия ( #main-top .line ) оказалась под ним и не виднелась. Задавать background нельзя. Нужно для мобильной версии, что бы при уменьшении экрана линия не заходила на контент.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100px;
     height: 100px;   
    max-width: 1300px;
    z-index: 100;
    margin-left:-0px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
#main-top {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 180px;
    margin-top: 90px;
}

#main-top .line {
    width: 150px;
    height: 1px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top: 5px;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(178,37,63,1);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(178,37,63,1) 0%, rgba(219,59,56,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(178,37,63,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(219,59,56,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(178,37,63,1) 0%, rgba(219,59,56,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(178,37,63,1) 0%, rgba(219,59,56,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(178,37,63,1) 0%, rgba(219,59,56,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(178,37,63,1) 0%, rgba(219,59,56,1) 100%);
```

```html
<div id="main-top" class="outer">
                <span class="line"></span>
                <div class="wrapper">
                </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: а можно узнать зачем Вам это?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Для мобильной версии. При уменьшении разрешения экрана  линия сдвигается и заходит на контент. Хотелось бы этого избежать.

Comment: У вас линия 150px, вы под какие экраны разрабатываете?

Comment: @ВладиславЖидко Это для примера 150px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@media screen and (max-width: npx) { // где n - длина wrapper
  #main-top .line {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: по другому никак?

Comment: Не устраивает то, что мы конкретно задаём длину или то, что используется "display" вместо "z-index"?

Comment: То что мы используем display. Не хотелось бы скрывать ее сразу. Желательно что бы эта линия существовало как можно дольше.

Comment: Я что-то не понимаю,как можно дольше, это до какого момента? Если будет задан background, можете поменять "display" на "z-index". Можно использовать "opacity: 0"